# Android AOSP Lock Screen rotation

Tags: android, android-source, landscape, lockscreen

I am building a device running on Android (9) that is normally used with the display in landscape mode. I have found a way to set the the home screen to landscape as well as fix the custom application that comes with the device to landscape, but I haven't found a way to do so for the Lock Screen (aka Keyguard). Is this at all possible?

Note: I do have the complete AOSP source code available for editing and building, I just don't know where to make the required changes. The AndroidManifest.xml of frameworks/base/packages/Keyguard is surprisingly empty.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to make some changes in you device make file and packages.
First: add this to you main device make file, and remove android.hardware.screen.portrait.xml package.

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.screen.landscape.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.screen.landscape.xml \
```

Second: Create an overlay config.xml file. it should be on overlay directory of the target directory (device/{vendor-of-you-device}/{model-of-your-device}/overlay/framework/base/res/res/values). then add this configuration
file (config.xml)

```
<resources>
    <bool name="config_forceDefaultOrientation">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Note: This way work for android 9 and all of the older versions, there is another way for android 10 and older.

Note: please make sure that the overlay directory path is defined in your make file so system use your overlays.

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS += device/{vendor-of-you-device}/{model-of-your-device}/overlay
```

Note: you have to provide framework overlays in you target path (device/{vendor-of-you-device}/{model-of-your-device}/overlay) for changing the display orientation or any other framework property and not changing the android internal framework configuration because it is not safe or recommended.

Comment: Thanks. But for some reason it didn't work on my device. I did not have the android.hardware.screen.portrait.xml installed on my device.mk. There already was on overlay file present on a slightly different path: (device/qcom/sdm845/overlay/framework/base/core/res/res/values) so I added the bool value there.

Comment: OK , did you test after you added the boolean value ? still no luck ?

Comment: yes no luck. how can i check if the overlay is actually loaded? i could be there but not loaded.

Comment: the overlay path should be on you device.mk or Boardconfig.mk. if you have included that path, the overlays will load and include automatically by android build system.